# Solve non-hex digit Error while using XSL Transformation With MobileFirst Adapter

Tags: xml, json, xslt-1.0, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

1. My XML data contains "\" characters in the xml.
2. It works fine when I didn't use Transformation in Mobilefirst Adapter.
3. But when I use Transformation via xsl in MobielFirst it throws error like below

   errors": [
                 "non-hex digit on line 4, column 471",
                 "The returned InvocationResult must be a valid JSON Object."
              ],
4. I found out it is caused through the Slash "\" which is present in my XML.
5. The same .XSL code works fine in others except in MobileFirst how to solve this error.
6. When I remove/comment "DESCRIPTION" `<xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION" />` it works fine.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <Envelope>
        <Body>
            <QueryResponse>
                <CLASSIFICATIONSSet>
                    <CLASSSTRUCTURE>
                        <CLASSIFICATIONID>Kawin</CLASSIFICATIONID>
                        <CLASSSTRUCTUREID>1001</CLASSSTRUCTUREID>
                        <CLASSUSEWITH>
                            <OBJECTNAME>1</OBJECTNAME>
                        </CLASSUSEWITH>
                        <CLASSUSEWITH>
                            <OBJECTNAME>2</OBJECTNAME>
                        </CLASSUSEWITH>
                        <CLASSUSEWITH>
                            <OBJECTNAME>3</OBJECTNAME>
                        </CLASSUSEWITH>
                        <CLASSUSEWITH>
                            <OBJECTNAME>4</OBJECTNAME>
                        </CLASSUSEWITH>
                        <DESCRIPTION>End User Issue \ Telco</DESCRIPTION>
                        <HIERARCHYPATH>Good \ BAD</HIERARCHYPATH>
                        <OBJECTNAME>1</OBJECTNAME>
                    </CLASSSTRUCTURE>
                </CLASSIFICATIONSSet>
            </QueryResponse>
        </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
               >
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        {


                'ClassificationData': [
                    <xsl:for-each select="*//CLASSSTRUCTURE">


                                    {
                                        "CLASSSTRUCTUREID" : '<xsl:value-of select="CLASSSTRUCTUREID" />', 
                                        "DESCRIPTION" : '<xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION" />' ,
                                        "CLASSIFICATIONID" : '<xsl:value-of select="CLASSIFICATIONID" />',
                                        "OBJECTNAME" : '<xsl:value-of select="OBJECTNAME" />',

                                         "CLASSUSEWITH" : [

                                            <xsl:for-each select="CLASSUSEWITH">
                                             {
                                                    "OBJECTNAME" : "<xsl:value-of select="OBJECTNAME" />"
                                             } ,
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        ]
                                    },
                       </xsl:for-each>
                    ]
      </xsl:choose>
        }
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You don't show your input. You don't show your XSLT. You don't show your output. How to you expect that anyone can help you?

Comment: 2 min ill show u still i am editing the question

Comment: @Tomalak can u see it now

Comment: **JSON is not text.** JSON is a markup format for structured data, very much like XML. You cannot create JSON with `<xsl:output mode="text">` because XSLT processors simply do not know how to encode JSON correctly.

Comment: @Tomalak that will be carried out my our Mobilefirst Adpater so that's not the probelm. since you are good in xml stuff ill ask you this i want to replace all the text in description containing ""\" with ""\\" will it be possible in XSLT.

Comment: No, it won't be carried out by the MobileFirst adapter. Your XSL stylesheet transforms input XML to something that looks a bit like JSON, but isn't JSON. There won't be anything left for the MobileFirst adapter to carry out. -- In any case: Yes, you can do string replace operations in XSLT, just search StackOverflow, there are numerous examples. Look at the JSON spec for all the character replacements you have to make: http://json.org/ (Also search for other examples that try to convert XML to JSON to see a few of the problems you are going to face.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73732/discussion-between-kawinesh-sk-and-tomalak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i made the Adapter working by replacing "\" backward slash with " \\ " double backward slash and a space at the beggining and end of the Double slash.

***XSL***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="text"  encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        {

                'ClassificationData': [

        <xsl:for-each select="*//CLASSSTRUCTURE">


                                    {
                                         "CLASSSTRUCTUREID" : '
            <xsl:value-of select="CLASSSTRUCTUREID" />', 


            <xsl:variable name="DESC">
                <xsl:value-of select='DESCRIPTION' />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="repString">
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="haystack" select="$DESC" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="search" select="'\'" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="' \\ '" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>


                                        "DESCRIPTION" : "
            <xsl:value-of select='$repString'/>" , 
                                        "CLASSIFICATIONID" : '
            <xsl:value-of select="CLASSIFICATIONID" />',
                                        "OBJECTNAME" : '
            <xsl:value-of select="OBJECTNAME" />', 

                                         "CLASSUSEWITH" : [


            <xsl:for-each select="CLASSUSEWITH">
                                             {
                                                    "OBJECTNAME" : "
                <xsl:value-of select="OBJECTNAME" />"
                                             } ,

            </xsl:for-each>
                                        ]
                                    },

        </xsl:for-each>

                    ]



        }

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="string-replace">
        <xsl:param name="haystack" />
        <xsl:param name="search" />
        <xsl:param name="replace" select="''" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($haystack, $search)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($haystack, $search)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$replace" />
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="haystack" select="substring-after($haystack, $search)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$search" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$haystack" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You might be able to get away with that. Just be aware that the next invalid character (like newlines) will break the output again.

Comment: No problem. My point was not to say "it's impossible", my point was that it's quite a bit more complex than it looks and that you're not finished just because it works right now.